# Worth it to replace a freezer gasket?

Tags: insulation, refrigerator, freezer

Our freezer gasket has gotten compressed, and is leaking cold air. My options are to buy a new refrigerator, buy a replacement gasket and replace it myself, or just live with it. I'd like to avoid buying a new fridge if possible; the fridge performs well otherwise. This is complicated by the fact that the freezer gasket is out of stock almost everywhere, and the places that have it are charging a premium price ($150-$200) for it. There is a substitute part recommended by the manufacturer (around $100) but it gets poor reviews; it does not seem to have been manufactured to the same standards of quality.

What would you recommend? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How old is the fridge?  Leaking cold air will make it work harder and longer, causing other systems to fail sooner.  An older than 10 or 15 years fridge might be worth replacing with a new one, compared to just replacing an expensive part.

Comment: Only you can decide if waiting on a $100+ gasket is "worth it" to you. As noted, an older fridge will be less efficient than a new one, so you may end up saving money in the long run by splashing some cash today. However, only _you_ can determine that. Unfortunately, this is off-topic.

Comment: Older fridges were really built to higher standards if the fridge is holding up other than the gasket I would want to replace the gasket. Some of the new stuff is just junk. My grand daughter had a dorm fridge that was discarded a nice 1/2 size one with a separate freezer compartment. It was less than 2 years old, I fixed the leak she used it for a few years at school and now it’s a back up fridge in the garage. But this is an opinion based question and is off topic.

Comment: Can you decompress it with a strip of small rubber tubing or screen spline?

Comment: Might also be able to build it back up with some silicone.  Clean gasket well, place a bead of silicone on it and cover the silicone with wide enough tape/paper.  Close the door and leave set.

Answer (score 3):

I replaced gaskets in my side-by-side (so two gaskets at one time, each in the $100 range, IIRC) a few years ago. Easy to do. Ridiculously expensive - my guess is that these are parts the manufacturers get in quantity for literally just a few $ each, but that is the case with a **lot** of replacement parts, and gaskets are a problem because they have to match the exact size - can't cut to fit.

In the end, comes down to age of the refrigerator/freezer because:

1 - The older it is, the more (relatively speaking) efficient a new appliance will be, so that the savings in energy costs will help to pay for the appliance.

2 - The older it is, the more likely that something else will break. Depending on the part, that may be something inexpensive and easy, or may be prohibitively expensive.

The brand/model has *some* bearing on this too. The equation on a Sub-Zero (if you would replace it with a similar appliance) is quite different from a run-of-the-mill GE or Whirlpool.